# Replace regex Match with other value

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have a query like this:

```
select * from tdirectories where tdirectories.parent in 
( 
    select max(tdirectories.directoryid) from tdirectories 
    where tdirectories.ntfsdrivedocuid in 
    ( 
        select ntfsdrivedocuid from tntfsdrives, tntfsdrivedocu 
        where tntfsdrivedocu.ntfsdriveid = tntfsdrives.ntfsdriveid and tntfsdrives.hostid in 
        (
            select tdocu.hostid from tdocu, tshares 
            here tdocu.docuid = tshares.docuid 
            and tdocu.archiv = 0 
        )
        and tntfsdrivedocu.archiv = 0 
    )
    and tdirectories.pathhash  in (select tshares.pathhash from tshares   ) 
)
```

What I want to do is that by using RegEx I want to find this part:

```
select max(tdirectories.directoryid)
```

Inside the `max` can be any value. I want to find it and remove, as result i will have

```
select tdirectories.directoryid
```

The regex I have created looks like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(select\\s.+select)\\smax\\s*\\((?<VAR>[^)]+)\\)");
```

But this does not solve my issue. What am i missing?

Comment: is the outer query always "select * " ??

Comment: Yes, it is. I want to select all the cases that after select there is max and remove the max

Comment: I guess the capturing group should work for that...  try out this : select\s*(max\(([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+)\)) and replace group {1} with group {2} in the given query text.... \

Comment: Thaks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for (in free mode):

```
select       # select literally
\            # a space
max          # max literally
\(([^)]+)\)  # capture anything inside the parentheses
```

And use the first group (`$1`), see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sT4eZ2/2).